# In mariadb can you dump the default mysql database with mysqldump? Error 1045. Access denied!

Tags: mariadb

```
mysqldump --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --port=xx --user=xxx -p mysql
Enter password:
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

My user has all privileges.

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  show grants for 'xxx'@'xx.xx.xx.xx';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for xxx@xx.xx.xx.xx                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `xxx`@`xx.xx.xx.xx` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx' |
| GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES ON `mysql`.* TO `xxx`@`xx.xx.xx.xx`                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Other databases worked.

I also tried with a different server, it doesn't seems to work?

Comment: Does your user have `SUPER` privilege?  Normally it is not practical to reload that system directory.

Comment: Yes, he has super: SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE super_priv='Y'; What do you mean with reload the system directory? On another mariadb system dumping mysql database works with the same user and rights?!

Comment: @RickJames: I got it working but only with all these options: --hex-blob=TRUE --routines=TRUE --triggers=TRUE --compact=TRUE --compression-algorithms=zlib,uncompressed --column-statistics=0 --single-transaction=TRUE . Maybe not all of them are needed?

Comment: Puzzling.  None of those settings _seem_ to involve "Access".  File a bug report with MariaDB.